# дёргается навбар при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, flexbox

есть страница с навбаром, который с помощью JS уменьшается при прокрутке вниз, при этом всегда оставаясь вверху (`position: sticky`). если быстро и сильно прокручивать всё работает правильно, если же прокрутить немного, то навбар начинает дёргатся вверх-вниз как аццкий сотона, в примере ниже видно. есть идеи как исправить?

я вообще понимаю, что это из-за того самого `position: sticky`, так как если поставить `fixed`, то скроллится нормально, только вот `fixed` не работает с flexbox.

```js
navbar_scroll();

function navbar_scroll() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 30) {
      $('nav').css('height', '50px');
      $('[id=nav-link]').css('padding', '15px 20px');
      $('[id=nav-icon]').css('padding', '15px 10px');
    } else {
      $('nav').css('height', '160px');
      $('[id=nav-link]').css('padding', '71px 20px');
      $('[id=nav-icon]').css('padding', '71px 10px');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 160px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  background: white;
}

nav .nav-section-logo {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

nav .nav-section-link {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

nav .nav-link {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Major Mono Display', monospace;
  padding: 71px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: coral;
}

nav .nav-icon {
  padding: 71px 10px;
}

p.lorem {
  padding: 600px 0;
  background-color: #323232;
  margin: 0 60px 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-section-logo">
    <a href="#" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-section-link">
    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">Main</a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">Photography</a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">About me</a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-icon" class="nav-link nav-icon">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-icon" class="nav-link nav-icon">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-icon" class="nav-link nav-icon">
      <i class="fab fa-github fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>

<p class="lorem">lorem</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: сделайте `position: fixed;`

Comment: @MishaSaidov, написал ведь, `fixed` не работает с флексбоксом, оно ломает навбар (конкретно в данном случае, он отображается только на часть страницы).

Comment: Упс, поторопился. А `width:100%` и `position: fixed;` вместе не пробовали?

Comment: @MishaSaidov, так, сейчас чувствую себя максимально тупым что сам не додумался к этой строчке. благодарю, работает.

upd: теперь верхняя часть контента залазит под навбар

Comment: решается добавлением `padding-top` к элементу контента, но может есть какой-то более элегантный вариант?

Comment: Решение через `padding-top` - классический вариант. Посмотрите даже в код StackOverflow. У `body` задан `padding-top: 50px;`

Comment: @MishaSaidov, да, вижу. благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
navbar_scroll();

function navbar_scroll() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > parseInt($('nav').css('height')) - 20) {
      $('nav').css('height', '50px');
      $('[id=nav-link]').css('padding', '15px 20px');
      $('[id=nav-icon]').css('padding', '15px 10px');
    } else {
      $('nav').css('height', '160px');
      $('[id=nav-link]').css('padding', '71px 20px');
      $('[id=nav-icon]').css('padding', '71px 10px');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 160px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  background: white;
}

nav .nav-section-logo {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

nav .nav-section-link {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

nav .nav-link {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Major Mono Display', monospace;
  padding: 71px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: coral;
}

nav .nav-icon {
  padding: 71px 10px;
}

p.lorem {
  padding: 600px 0;
  background-color: #323232;
  margin: 0 60px 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-section-logo">
    <a href="#" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-section-link">
    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">Main</a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">Photography</a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-link" class="nav-link">About me</a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-icon" class="nav-link nav-icon">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-icon" class="nav-link nav-icon">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="nav-icon" class="nav-link nav-icon">
      <i class="fab fa-github fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>

<p class="lorem">lorem</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```